# Call an object's method from Django's Template on click

Tags: python, django

What I have currently is:

```
<ul>
    {% for object in object_list %}
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>{{ object.property1}}</li>
                <li>{{ object.property2}}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

What I want to do is call a method (which would be {{ object.remove }}) if, and only if, the user presses the remove button. I need to use one of the object's properties in the remove method, so it has to be that specific object's remove() call.

I know how to call a function inside the *view*, as there are many questions about that, but I'm not sure how that will help? Same with AJAX calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get object from database, usually by id that you get from URL and do your call.

For example you have a `Post` with this line in `url.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/remove/$', views.remove, name='remove'),
    # ...
)
```

Then you have `views.py`:

```
from .models import Post

def detail(request, post_id):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Error 404")
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'post': post})

def remove(request, post_id):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=question_id)
        post.remove()
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Error 404")
    return render(request, 'confirm.html', {'message': 'Post was removed'})
```

And in your template add link to `remove` view:

```
<ul>
{% for post in post_list %}
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/{{ post.id }}/remove/">{{ post.id}}</a></li>
            <!-- or add AJAX call to this URL -->
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

That is how you usually deal with it in Django.

As long as post_id is just an function parameter you can use it as index id for your own stored list or dictionary. But make sure that your regexp in `urls.py` rules apply to your needs. In my example `r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/remove/$'` looks for integers (because of `\d+` rule). More information in [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using a database? I ask because the list of objects is determined at runtime.

Comment: Where is your object list is stored then? Is is array or dict? Then you can use `post_id` in `remove` view function as a key to this array. But that means that list of objects should be the same between calls. Usually this means that it is defined in the same file.

Comment: I should be able to just refer to its index, then?

EDIT: Still typing more, accidentally pressed enter.

Comment: Okay, it won't let me edit it...   

To refer to its index, the list of objects must remain the same. What are my options to keeping it the same? I could just use Models, but it seemed like a pain to continually add and delete them from the database.  

The way I obtain this list of objects is by calling a 'get_objects()' function, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Updated my last section. Actually you don't need to store everything in database. But it is right place if you have a lot of data that usually updated by users or removed/added TTW. Ofc, you can just have your own dictionary in code, but then you will not be able to remove items from it, because it will be so called "hard coded" into your file. Getting things from DB is simple enough to use it in every view.

Comment: the cache backend would be an alternative to the database... you really need somewhere outside your python code to store these objects if you want the changes to persist

Comment: You can store data in a cache-based session backend.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about how a website works...

1. The browser sends a request to your web server for a particular url
2. Your web server passes the request details to your Django application
3. Django looks in your urlconf to find a view matching that url
4. Django calls the url function (or method of view class) with a `request` object
5. The view code renders a template, producing a string of HTML
6. The web server sends the HTML back to the user's browser

So, with this in mind, it's clear that the only way to interact with Django when the user clicks a button on the web page is for the browser to send a new request.

In short, you need to use AJAX.